# How can I train a model to modify a vector by rewarding the model based on the modified vectors nearest neighbors?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, training, information-retrieval, vector-space-models

I am experimenting with a document retrieval system in which I have documents represented as vectors. When queries come in, they are turned to vectors by the same method as used for the documents. The query vector's k nearest neighbors are retrieved as the results. Each query has a known answer string.

In order to improve performance, I am now looking to create a model that modifies the query vector. What I was looking to do was use a model that rewarded the model for each of the top k nearest neighbor's corresponding documents that contain the answer string and punish when the string is not present.

In looking for a solution I have been mainly finding results related to multiple rounds of discrete decision making, so I am also not sure if this would count as reinforcement learning or something else entirely. Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is an existing technique. Read about the triplet- and contrastive losses; e.g., [Optimizing Contrastive/Rank/Triplet Loss in Tensorflow for Neural Information Retrieval](https://hanxiao.github.io/2017/11/08/Optimizing-Contrastive-Rank-Triplet-Loss-in-Tensorflow-for-Neural/). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query is common in search engineering/information retrieval. It is commonly called query rewriting for search engines. There are many variations such as: query expansion, query relaxation, and query scoping.